# Current mirror and differential amplifier

Tags: differential

[image]
Hi,
In the attached figure, I am not sure how to formulate the relation between \$I_{ref}\$ and the DC currents through the four transistors \$Q_1-Q_4\$, given that \$I_{B1,2,3,4,5,6}\$ aren't neglected and that \$\alpha=0.98\$.
I found \$I_{ref}\$ to be \$1mA\$. Now, is \$I_{ref}=I_{c1}+I_{b1}+I_{b2}\$?

Comment: Look more closely, the \$I_{ref}\$ branch connects to \$Q_1\$, \$Q_2\$, \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_4\$

Comment: How about, \$I_{ref}=I_{c1}+I_{b1}+I_{b2}+I_{c2}+I_{b2}+I_{b3}\$?

Comment: @peripatein Darned thing wouldn't work right with those specs. But I'm sure you are supposed to assume it does. So look, \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ are matched and so will equally share your current. I know that \$V_{BE}\$ (tied to \$I_S\$ anyway) is just given to you as fixed, but in a current mirror what does it mean about their \$V_{BE}\$ when two BJTs share the same collector current? Any implications arrive to you here?

Comment: And I also know that \$I_{c1}=I_{c2}=I_{c3}=I_{c4}\$, right?

Comment: Why is the above relation I wrote between \$I_{ref}\$ and \$I_{c1,2},I_{b1-3}\$ wrong?

Comment: @peripatein I don't recall saying it was wrong. Can you work out the currents, now?

Comment: But what was your caveat, should you care to explain more carefully? Moreover, bearing in mind that all the collector currents are equal, don't I have pretty much everything I need to solve the \$I_{ref}\$ relation?

Comment: @peripatein Yes, I think you have what you need and I think you have to assume that the base currents in all four BJTs are the same (using the Early voltage in \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_4\$ to impact their collector currents only.)

Comment: I get \$I_{C_1}=I_{C_2} \approx 480.77\:\mu\textrm{A}\$. That's going to largely determine your differential-pi amp currents, except that \$V_A\$ affects them of course.

Comment: I get a similar result. Is it correct then that \$V_{CE3}=V_{CE4}=6.8V\$ and that \$I_{EE}=0\$?

Comment: Is the difference in base voltages in the diff-pi zero?

Comment: Would it not be correct to say that \$V_{c3}=V_{c4}=-0.7V\$?

Comment: I mean, isn't \$V_{b5}=V_{b6}=0V\$?

Comment: @peripatein You know the currents in \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_4\$. But your problem says nothing about \$V_{cm}\$ (which is fine as we can just assume it is "workable") and nothing about your \$V_d\$, which I have to assume is set up as a differential signal input -- half on one side, half on the other. But you need that signal to say anything about \$I_{EE}\$. Right?

Comment: @jonk, may we continue this via the chat? Alternatively, suppose I am asked to find the DC current through all the branches and voltages at all nodes, without neglecting \$I_{b1-6}\$ and remembering that \$\alpha = 0.98\$, and while neglecting Early effect in DC current calculations -- may I then choose \$V_{cm}=0\$, i.e. voltage at base equals zero? As otherwise I cannot fully determine the voltages!

Comment: @peripatein I don't have time right now to chat. I'm sorry. I would, otherwise. Have you *ever* looked at an MC1496?? Oh, well. Look, \$Q_5\$ and \$Q_6\$ need to be "jacked up a bit" so that their emitters have some room to work with, without squishing down on the collectors of mirrors \$Q_3\$ and \$Q_4\$. If you allow a couple of volts for the mirrors, then another volt for those emitters, and then a little more room for signal/2, the common mode voltage supply has to be at least four volts over your bottom rail. \$V_{CM}\$ jacks things up so they work but it shouldn't impact those currents.

Comment: @peripatein But you don't have any specification for \$V_{CM}\$. What does that tell me? I don't know. I just have to assume it is valid. However, whatever it happens to be, without a signal (\$V_D\$), the emitters will be a diode drop below it. Yes? And the collector currents will just "run through" them, yes? Also, \$I_{EE}=0\$, yes? From that, you can figure the drops across those two resistors on top, yes? Now ask yourself what happens when you add some \$V_D\$ here? (This whole thing is just a diff-pi amp.)